# Spring Profile Active is not setting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to run the below command to start a springboot application

```bash
java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///log4j.properties -Dspring.profiles.active=local -cp ./target/app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar MainClass
```

the jar above is prepared using `maven-assembly-plugin` the configuration for which is

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-assembly-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>MainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Main class looks like

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        log.info(System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active"));
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(AcctrvDataProcessor.class, args);
        log.info(Arrays.toString(ctx.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles()));
        int exitCode = SpringApplication.exit(ctx);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

When I run the application from the above command I am seeing the below log:

```
15:45:07.091 [main] INFO MainClass - local
15:46:07.091 [main] INFO MainClass - No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
```

What could be preventing the spring profile actives from being set?

Comment: Remove the `maven-assembly-plugin` add `spring-boot-maven` plugin.

Comment: What would be difference?

Comment: THat you use the proper way for a Spring Boot application to be packaged. Next to that use `--spring.profiles.active` .

Answer (score 1):

Why are you calling the main class?  This is a spring boot application, so try starting by just invoking the jar.

```
java -jar -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///log4j.properties -Dspring.profiles.active=local app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

And note it is important to have the -D parameters before the application jar or they will not be recognized.

If you have a hard requirement to use the -cp (classpath) amd not call the jar directly then you can set an environment variable to set the active profile in your shell and then trying starting the spring app that way.

```
export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local
```

Comment: I have a hard requirement to use `java -cp`. Is there anyway to pass spring profile active with this config?

Comment: You can try setting via environment variable.  I have modified my answer to include that option.

Comment: @Varun Is this homework?  If not, express to your manager to come to this question so we can explain why their requirement doesn't make any sense.  You can just set the environment variable, `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local` and run it as you were.